# Get list of dictionary elements ordered by dictionary key

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `d` for which the keys are all strings. Now when I do:

```
for key in d:
   print(d[key])
```

I get the elements of `d` is some "random" order. How can I force the element of `d` to come out sorted by the lexicographical order?

Comment: You might want to read [dictionaries python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python dictionary sort by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sort before iterating.

```
for key in sorted(d):
```

Comment: 21 seconds win according to timestamp

Answer (score 8):

Use `sorted()` to sort any iterable, including a dictionary:

```
for key in sorted(d):
   print(d[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionaly to those answers, if your dictionary is immutable but have significant amount of items and need to be read more often than once, it might be useful to repack items using the [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) container.